# iOS Plist Overwritten each time I save

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Using plist to save and load basic variables in iOS App.  Problem I've encountered is that my plist appears to be erased each time I save new data.  I've been struggling for days on this and I'm sure there has to be a simple solution.  Below is my code for both my SaveData and LoadData.  Thank you!

```
- (void) saveData{
// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: age, activityLevel, activityLevelFactorNumber, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Age", @"ActivityLevel", @"ActivityLevelFactor", nil]];

NSString *error = nil;
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

load data (I'm able to load from last plist saved only):

```
- (void) LoadData {
  // get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// check to see if Data.plist exists in documents
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
}

// read property list into memory as an NSData object
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
// convert static property list into dictionary object
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

Comment: `I'm able to load from last plist saved only`, yes, exactly, whatever you saved last will be what the file contains.

Comment: Wain - is there a simple way to load in what was in the file, add to it, then save it?

Comment: Yeah, and you already have 99% of the code because you have a method to load it. About the only thing missing is `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Wain - I tried that but don't think I used it correctly.  What I did was create this: NSMutableDictionary *mutableTemp = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] mutableCopy].

Comment: The main question is how the new data should be added, what are you expecting to be in the file after the new save?

Comment: I'm looking to add a combination of strings and numbers, and even update the existing strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change your `LoadData` method so it returns the loaded data (rather then loading it into an instance variable or whatever it does currently). Also, correct the naming for conventions:

```
- (NSDictionary *)loadData { ...
```

I'd also refactor the path code into its own method:

```
- (NSString *)pathForSavingData { ...
```

Then, when you come to save:

```
- (void)appendAndSaveData {
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [self pathForSavingData];

    // create dictionary with values in UITextFields
    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[self loadData] mutableCopy];

    NSDictionary *newEntries = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[age, activityLevel, activityLevelFactorNumber, nil]
                                                           forKeys:@[@"Age", @"ActivityLevel", @"ActivityLevelFactor", nil]];

    [plistDict addEntriesFromDictionary:newEntries];

    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Wain - this worked great and was extremely helpful.  I also appreciate the tips on writing better code.